# What does "Chief Engineer Emeritus" means?

Tags: management, leadership, role

Recently I've came across a few profiles on LinkedIn with title as "Chief Engineer Emeritus".

What does **Chief Engineer Emeritus** means in an organization ?

Comment: On LinkedIn it could mean anything, as there is no control of titles.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows too little effort before posting, as a simple search on the internet gives the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Emeritus" [is used when a person previously held a position and has served so well that they are given the honour of the title perpetually](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emeritus), even though they are no longer actually doing the work entailed. For example a professor who has been a renowned leader in their field might be awarded the title of "Professor Emeritus" after they retire. It might entitle them to keep an office and take part in department meetings, but usually doesn't come with any duties or pay.

Answer (score 0):

Emeritus: Someone who held the named position previously. Most commonly used in academia, but this isn't an unreasonable use of the term. (Websearch or dictionary search on the word will tell you more.)

Note that on LinkedIn it probably means the person is no longer in that organization, not just no longer serving in that position.

Comment: It's not just "previously" You don't become "emeritus" by being fired, for example.

Comment: @DJClayworth But worth noting that you can call yourself whatever you want on LinkedIn, so it could very well be that they were fired and decided to replace the title with Emeritus, either as a tongue-in-cheek joke or an act of defiance.

Comment: We also don't know that they were chief engineer, or what "chief engineer" meant at that company. As I've said before, my early resume included  "Master Electrician and Lighting Crew Chief" at a local summer theater group -- generously credited that way in the plays' program books -- when in fact I was the only electrician and the entire lighting crew. There's the title you use to describe the job, the title the company used to describe the job, and what the job actually involved... and resumes, including LinkedIn, are prone to puffery.